# Is it possible to update or alter smart contract (chaincode) deployed in Hyperledger network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Is it possible to update or alter smart contract (chaincode) deployed in Hyperledger network? i.e. I have deployed a smart contract, Blocks are created with transactions, after some time, I want to alter the chain code, is it possible to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically we cannot update the installed chaincode for a certain channel, but we can use the chaincode version to distinguish with the newer updated chaincode from older chaincode (**we do upgrade** [Chaincode for Operators - upgrade](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/chaincode4noah.html#upgrade)).
To use use new updated chaincode, we have to install the updated chaincode with new version (*here in example version 1 which was version 0 before*) with same chaincode name as the older chaincode name on a peer:

```
peer chaincode install -p chaincodedev/chaincode/sacc -n mycc -v 1
```

See the `-v` tag in above command with **version 1** and `-n` tag with chaincode name.

Then upgrade the chaincode on the channel:

```
peer chaincode upgrade -n mycc -v 1 -c '{"Args":["a","10"]}' -C myc
```

See the `-v` tag again in above command with **version 1** , `-n` tag with chaincode name and `-C` tag with channel name on which it is instantiated.

So, once chaincode is installed and upgraded it retains on the channel and we can use newer updated chaincode by upgrading them. When we invoke the chaincode on a peer it will invoke the latest chaincode that is installed on a channel.
e.g. :

```
peer chaincode invoke -n mycc -c '{"Args":["set", "a", "20"]}' -C myc
```

**References**:
1) : peer chaincode upgrade example ( https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-upgrade-example )

Comment: You don't need to call `instantiate` again after having installed the new chaincode. You just need to run `peer chaincode install` and `peer chaincode upgrade` commands (`Init()` method is also called during chaincode upgrade, this is why care must be taken to avoid resetting states when upgrading)

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with Hyperledger Composer I would add to the previous answer saying that with composer you would achieve the same upgrade with these commands:

`composer network install -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -a my-network@0.0.2.bna`

and

`composer network upgrade -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n my-network -V 0.0.2`

to upgrade to v0.0.2 of the network (chaincode).

Comment: Thanks or your reply